# ¿como usar data-remote de Bootstrap validator con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

Entiendo que la respuesta es código de estado `200` o `4xx` pero no logro que viaje la petición.

```
<div class="form-group  col-md-6">
  {!! Form::label('correo', 'Correo electrónico')!!}
  {!! Form::email('correo',null,['class'=>'form-control form-control-sm','required','data-remote'=>'/usuarios/valida_correo?data=email'])!!}
</div>
```

He probado de distintas formas pero no viaja la petición, cuando observo el comportamiento en la pestaña de `Network` de la consola de depuración de `Chrome`.

Comment: Podrias añadir el contenido html que se te genera en la ejecución?, para obtener más información de las peticiones que estás realizando y su estado puedes usar Fiddler: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Esa opción está deprecada desde bootstrap v3.3 y eliminada en v4, revisa tu versión.